# How to find if the txt file is empty or not? Conditions: The file is empty (throw exception) ,the file has only spaces and new line(throw exception)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

[image]

I have a file scores1.txt.
Task: to check if the file is empty or not and throw appropriate exceptions

- Case 1: File is empty. Throw exception "file is empty"
- Case 2: File has spaces and new line character(\n). Throw exception "file is empty"

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please paste code instead of images of it

Comment: @azro some issue with pasting code.. i tried indenting as well it shows error :(

Comment: `is_empty = file.read().lstrip() == ""`

Comment: An empty file is not an exception. I see Python making this error in other places. Popping an empty list should not throw an exception but should return None. There may be other opinions but they are wrong.

Comment: @StephenBoston An exception is just an a-typical/unexpected condition - it does not necessarily imply an error. Also, it would be an obvious bug to return `None` when popping from an empty list, since `None` is a valid value.

Comment: @ekhumoro Okay. But. In this case the empty file *is* an expected condition. On the other hand... I see your stack point: attempting to open a non existent file should raise an exception not simply return None. Perhaps you can make a point that this case is of that class.

Comment: @ekhumoro Ah. I see the stack point. To avoid the exception I should init the stack with a push(none). Perhaps that's what everyone's been doing. Ah sigh.

Comment: @StephenBoston The vast majority of files aren't empty/whitespace-only. If a program reads a file, it's usually with the expectation that it contains meaningful content. If it doesn't, it's perfectly reasonable to raise an exception. This is especially true if the file was specified by the user, since the exception-handler could then display a message informing the user that the file is invalid. Silencing errors/exceptions is usually a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.strip()` to remove any whitespace and newlines from it, after reading the whole file, if that comes to be empty : file was empty or only whitespace characters

```
with open("scores1.txt") as fic:
    content = fic.read().strip()
    if not content:
        raise Exception("File is empty")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 if not any(line.strip() for line in open("scores.txt")):
      raise Exception("empty file")
```

Comment: This has the benefit that it avoids reading the whole file into memory and will also terminate early (i.e. at the first non-empty line).